# How do I add fines based off 60 minute intevals?

Tags: java

I have a program for my computer science class where I must ticket a parked car if they're parked for more than 60 minutes. The `ParkingTicket` class `calculateFine()` method takes `minutes` as an argument, and should then give a base fine for the first hour, plus 10 dollars for each additional hour parked. Say if I were parked a total of 150 minutes, my ticket would then be $35 ($25 for the first hour and $10 for the second with no penalty for the remaining 30 minutes).

What I had in mind was using `if(minutes%60)` to check if the minutes is divisible by 60, but then I don't know how to make the program check how many TIMES it's divisible, minus the first 60 minutes. And now that I think about it, that means it'd be false if `minutes` wasn't divisible by 60, meaning it wouldn't execute at all..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: If I tell you I was parked in your lot for 1729 minutes, how many hours is that? How did you figure it out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple way would be to subtract the initial 60 from the total minutes and then add the 25 to the running sum, then do a while loop subtracting 60 from the total until it is less than 0 while updating the running fine total.

Comment: I used your suggestion to subtract each 60 minutes while `minutes >= 60`, and added the 25 dollar fine when `minutes >= 60 && minutes < 119`, and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate the number of hours from the minutes. If the number of hours is > 0, then the fine will just be a simple calculation.

```
final int BASE_FINE = 25;
final int HOURLY_FINE = 10;

int fine = 0;
int hours = minutes / 60;

if (hours > 0)
    fine = BASE_FINE + (HOURLY_FINE * (hours - 1));

return fine;
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I like it all the way down to the omission of curly braces and the use of integer types to do the rounding implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, after appropriate variable declarations, of course:

```
fine = 0;
if (minutes > 60) /* did you mean more than 60 like you said, or >= 60? */
{
fine = 25;
minutes -= 60;
fine += 10*Math.floor(minutes/60);
}
```

This is a more clear way to break it down:

```
fine = 0;
hours = Math.floor(minutes/60); /* automatically ignores extra minutes */
if (hours >= 1) {
fine += 25; /* charge $25 fine for the first hour */
}
if (hours >= 2) {
fine += 10*(hours-1); /* charge $10 fine per hour for subsequent hours */
}
```

You should definitely not use a loop. That exposes your program to DOS attacks through an easy submission of large integers to your program. Never use loops for a simple math problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you covered loops yet? If so consider using a while loop, something like this:

```
while(minutesParked >= 60) {
    fine += 10;
    minutesParked -= 60;
}
```

If minutesParked is greater than or equal to 60 minutes, we add $10 to the fine and subtract the 60 minutes we've just accounted for from minutesParked. This loop continues executing until there are fewer than 60 minutes remaining in minutesParked which according to your post there are no penalties for.